# Can the complementiser 고 be used along with the accusative case marker 를?

Tags: grammar

Since 고-led CP is comparable to DP, I am wondering whether it can be followed by any case marker. Moreover, since there are sentences such as
`갔다고만 말했다.` or `갔다고도 말했다.`, where the 고 is followed by some delimiter, it seems plausible that it can be followed by a case marker as well.
For example, can I say something like this?
`갔다고를 말했다.`

Comment: No, that's not grammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, 갔다고를 is never used as far as I know.

The reason is because such a 를 adds nothing.  갔다고 말했다 means someone "said *that they went*", with 갔다고 already acting as a direct object of 말했다.  걌다고**만** adds the sense of ***only** that*, and 갔다고**도** *that **as well***.  갔다고**는** would make it *they said **that at least***.  All these adds some useful nuance whereas 갔다고를 would mean exactly the same thing as 갔다고.  So there is absolutely no reason to add 를.

Comment: Also, we can probably argue that "갔다고" isn't even an object - it's a complement of the verb, but that doesn't necessarily make it an object. Consider a phrase like "라면 먹고 가라고 친구를 불렀다", which contains both a phrasal complement and an object.

Comment: Yes, it can take different grammatical role.  For example, it is a complement in a phrase like A를 B라고 부르다 = A를 B로 부르다 = Call A B.  In 라면 먹고 가라고 친구를 불렀다, the -라고 clause might even be adverbial too (like a shortened 라면 먹고 가라고 하며), since it doesn't appear tightly connected with 부르다 and should be distinguished from structures like A를 B라고 부르다,  I suppose grammar doesn't have a precise answer for all cases.